# How to ST_Split features in one table by features in another?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, splitting

I need to split polygons (layer 'pol') by both closed and non-closed linestrings (layer 'lin').

[image]
[image]

Unfortunately I don't get proper results running the following query.

```
CREATE VIEW splitted_pol AS
SELECT 
    g.path[1] as gid, 
    g.geom::geometry(polygon, SRID) as geom 
FROM
    (SELECT 
    (ST_Dump(ST_Split(pol.geom, lin.geom))).* 
    FROM pol, lin
) as g;
```

In my example ST_Split should create six polygons (layer 'splitted_pol').

[image]
[image]
 Does anybody know how to use ST_Split with QGIS/PostGIS?

Comment: You need to feed the the geoms recursively to `ST_Split`.

Comment: Can you please help me with the SQL query? I'm new to PostGIS.

Comment: What exactly does your input layers contain? I see layer 'pol' with a red square and a triangle polygon and layer 'lin' with only one dark blue vertical line. And why do you expect 6 polygons? I whould not take the "border" into account.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to illustrate the layers.

Comment: Any chance you could add the input geometries?

Comment: I will upload shape files if this might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create function something like this:

```
create or replace function ST_MultiSplit(geom Geometry, blades Geometry) RETURNS Geometry AS $$
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..ST_NumGeometries(blades)
     LOOP
        geom = ST_Split(geom, ST_GeometryN(blades, i));
     END LOOP;
  RETURN geom;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then use it like:

```
Select ST_AsEWKT(a.geom) from (
   select (ST_Dump(ST_MultiSplit(pol.geom, (
      select ST_MemUnion(lin.geom) from lin where ST_Intersects(pol.geom, lin.geom) = 't')
 ))).geom geom from pol) a;
```

This gives the six records you are expecting.  You may want to add some error checking/handling and I'm not sure about scalability.

Answer (score 4):

I am using postGIS sql to split feature by line in JAVA, and my code worked. my code is:

public  List splitGeometry(String geom1, String geom2) {

```
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>() ;
    try {

        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        String sql_stat = null;
        sql_stat = "select st_astext (a.geom)from (select ( st_dump(p_geom)).geom as geom FROM (SELECT  st_split(ST_GeomFromEWKT('"+geom1+"') ,ST_GeomFromEWKT('"+geom2+"'))AS p_geom) AS b) AS a;";
        System.out.println(sql_stat);
        ResultSet rs=  s.executeQuery(sql_stat);
        while (rs.next()){
            result.add(rs.getString(1)) ;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result ;
}
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm trying to figure out a PostGIS only solution since I don't know how to link QGIS with JAVA.

Comment: QGIS is written in C++ and there are Python bindings. So you can develop your own applications using those languages. You cannot use Java.You can use instead of postGIS.

Comment: Is there a way to split polygon features by linestring features using PostGIS without any C++/Python applications? I've no programming experience.

Comment: You use PostGIS and Java, Without the need for C++ and Python. You can also use the geotools in Java.