# Custom ST_MultiSplit PostgreSQL function error, to split one layer with another

Tags: postgresql, error, loop, function, st-split

I have a lines layer which I would like to split with a points layer.

I first created the a ST_MultiSplit function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_MultiSplit(geom Geometry, blades Geometry) RETURNS Geometry AS $$
BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..ST_NumGeometries(blades)
 LOOP
 geom = ST_Split(geom, ST_GeometryN(blades, i));
 END LOOP;
 RETURN geom;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This I got from http://themagiscian.com/2016/04/19/routing-in-brisbane-a-recipe-for-a-complete-web-app/ and [How to ST_Split features in one table by features in another?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146782/how-to-st-split-features-in-one-table-by-features-in-another/154078)

According to these two sites it should work. I even tried re-writing and and still get the same error. Cannot understand why it is not working

I do the select as described:

```sql
SELECT a.fclass, a.name, a.ref, a.oneway,(ST_Dump(ST_MultiSplit(a.the_geom, (
 SELECT ST_Union(no.ix) FROM  temp_dc no WHERE ST_intersects(no.ix,a.the_geom)
)))).geom 
as the_geom
FROM temp_dc_union a
```

But I keep on getting the same error:

> ERROR:  upper bound of FOR loop cannot be null
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_multisplit(geometry,geometry) line 3 at FOR with integer loop variable
> SQL state: 22004

Comment: the function is receiving a Null input, because `st_union` worked on no geometries, because `no` and `a` don't intersect each others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JGH pointed out, you either have null geometries in temp_dc or you're getting nulls in the st_union result.  You can filter those out:

```
SELECT a.fclass, a.name, a.ref, a.oneway,(ST_Dump(ST_MultiSplit(a.the_geom, 
  (SELECT geom from
    (SELECT ST_Union(no.ix) geom FROM  temp_dc no WHERE 
    ST_intersects(no.ix,a.the_geom) ) foo
  WHERE geom is not null and not st_isempty(geom)
  )))).geom 
as the_geom
FROM temp_dc_union a;
```

You could also handle the nulls in your function instead (return null when blades are empty or null):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_MultiSplit(INOUT geom Geometry, IN blades Geometry) 
language plpgsql STRICT AS $$
DECLARE
  g geometry;
BEGIN
  FOR g IN (select geom from st_dump(blades)) LOOP
    geom = ST_Split(geom, g);
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

*Edited based on improvements suggested by @geozelot

*2nd Edit:

A special function for splitting with a multipart is not necessary.  St_split already accepts multipart blades.  You're recreating what you would get from doing:

```
select st_split( (select the_geom from input_table),(select the_multipart_blade_geom from blade_table) );
```

OR

```
select st_split( (select the_geom from input_table),(select st_union(the_geom) from blade_table) );
```

Comment: Some thoughts: you want to define the function as `STRICT` to handle `NULL` input - it will skip the function invocation alltogether. Then, to save conditional branching and component access inside the loop, loop over a component dump instead, i.e. `... DECLARE cmp GEOMETRY; ... FOR cmp IN ( SELECT geom FROM ST_Dump(blades) ) LOOP ...`. Lastly, this is a good pace to use explicit parameter modes, i.e. `CREATE FUNCTION ST_MultiSplit(INOUT geom GEOMETRY, IN blade GEOMETRY) AS ...` (no `RETURNS GEOMETRY` and no `RETURN geom;`) - PG may optimize in-place parameter value updates.

Comment: I am still having the problem that it returns every piece of geometry where an individual point it is split with. I only need it to return the pieces of the lines where all points are split i.e. the single line when split with 3 points returns 4 pieces of lines. and it runs to long. I am really trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated

Comment: @Ian23 I don't understand what you mean.  Maybe you could add an image into your question or try to explain the problem a bit more clearly.  I would expect that if you split a line using 3 points, you would get 4 lines unless one of the points is on the end of the line.  If you cut a piece of string 3 times, you'd end up with 4 pieces.  Taking too long - try gist or spgist indexes on geom and blades (in the tables you're selecting from)

Comment: @geozelot I edited my answer to include your suggested improvements.  I appreciate your input - I learned a few things - thank you.