# Cutsom ST_Multisplit function returning more than one split line. How to only return one line split at various points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, splitting, network, road

I Have a modified version of the function from [How to ST_Split features in one table by features in another?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146782/how-to-st-split-features-in-one-table-by-features-in-another/154078)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Multi Split(geom Geometry, blades Geometry) RETURNS Geometry AS $$
DECLARE
  
  geom_collect varchar;
  blades_collect varchar;
  blade_count int;
  
BEGIN
 
 SELECT ST_AsText (ST_Collect (geom)) into geom_collect where ST_Intersects (geom, blades);
 SELECT ST_AsText (ST_Collect (blades)) into blades_collect where ST_Intersects (geom, blades);
 SELECT st_numgeometries(ST_GeomFromText(blades_collect)) into blade_count;
 IF blade_count is null or blade_count = 0 then
  RETURN null;
 ELSE
  FOR i IN 1..blade_count
  LOOP
  geom = ST_Split(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(geom_collect), 4326), ST_GeometryN(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(blades_collect), 4326), i));
  END LOOP;
  RETURN geom;
 END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The original funcion doe the same. It returns "double" geometries i.e. when one line is split with two points it returns 4 lines each split at a particular point:

[image: What happens]

I need it to do the following for an entire network:

[image: WHat I need is to do]

I am trying so split an road network at the intersections. I have already created the point "blade" layer where I want it split, and have a OSM extract.

How should I modify the function?

Comment: Inside the loop, you are always using the source `geom_collect` instead of using the previously split `geom`.

Comment: While there, you should remove the conversion to and from text. Work with geometries directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious approach - but I dare say you'd be surprised how badly it is going to perform, and fail.

The inherent *floating point* imprecision will make intersections between *Point* coordinates and a *LineString* (mathematically defined as a vector between two vertices) close to impossible for anything but a regularly gridded linework.

Besides, you likely get much faster results by splitting with a *MultiPoint* directly:

```
SELECT
  nw.<id>,
  dmp.path[1],
  dmp.geom
FROM
  <network> AS nw,
  LATERAL (
    SELECT
      ST_Split(nw.geom, ST_Collect(pt.geom)) AS geom
    FROM
      <point> AS pt
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(nw.geom, pt.geom)
  ) AS bd,
  LATERAL ST_Dump(bd.geom) AS dmp
```

Still mostly failing.

If you want to keep going with a pure PostGIS approach to simply node a network, better use `ST_Node` instead:

```
SELECT
  dmp.geom
FROM (
  SELECT
    ST_Node(
      ST_Collect(nw.geom)
    ) AS geom
  FROM
    <network> AS nw
) AS nd,
  LATERAL ST_Dump(nd.geom) AS dmp
;
```

However, there's no way to keep any of your network attributes with this approach!

---

I strongly suggest to consider moving to [*pgRouting*](https://pgrouting.org/), and specifically using the `pgr_nodeNetwork` function to not only *node* the network efficiently, but also create a true network topology with intact node/edge references.